# MyBatis foreach with spring not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I am Trying to update list for records but i got the following error in mybatis.

```
 org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'list' in 'class com.model.DataParameters'
```

and my mybatis xml query is as follow

```
<update id="deleteAssociatedEntityForParentEntity" parameterType="com.model.DataParameters">
    update dataTable set deleted = #{deleted}, syncTS = #{syncTS} where
    data_id in
    <foreach item="dataIds" index="index" collection="list"
        open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{dataIds}
    </foreach>
    and aData_type = #{dataType};

</update>
```

DataParameter class
getter setter has been declared in this class. 
dataIds is my list.

please let me know if is their any wrong in my query. why list is not taking in? Any other way Guys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your list name of class in collection attribute and an opcional name in item attribute to use below

you try this code:

```
<update id="deleteAssociatedEntityForParentEntity" parameterType="com.model.DataParameters">
    update dataTable set deleted = #{deleted}, syncTS = #{syncTS} where
    data_id in
    <foreach item="id" index="index" collection="dataIds"
        open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{id}
    </foreach>
    and aData_type = #{dataType};

</update>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you some additional check before the foreach .. dataIds should be List.

```
<update id="deleteAssociatedEntityForParentEntity" parameterType="com.model.DataParameters">
   update dataTable set deleted = #{deleted}, syncTS = #{syncTS} where 1=1
   <if test="dataIds!= null">
        and data_id in
        <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="dataIds"
        open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{item}
        </foreach>
    </if>
   and aData_type = #{dataType};
</update>
```

---

This is only a snippet of code

```
SqlSession session = sessionFactory.openSession();

Map<String, Object> mapParameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<Integer> listDataIds = ....

mapParameter.put("dataIds",listDataIds );

session.update("deleteAssociatedEntityForParentEntity",mapParameter);
```

Comment: But dude i am sending the list (dataIds) with parameter type
(com.model.DataParameters) object that's i think so no need to add null check , i am checking null before adding in the object(com.model.DataParameters) .

Comment: This is only a suggestion, i think that in order to mantain the query reusable you should add this check. Anyway the list should be  List<Integer>.

Comment: Still getting null dataIds see Parameters: 1(Integer), 1418640335416(Long), null, Student(String)